# Stripping IPv6 and port number from a string

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

I have a regex expression to check if a string contains an IP address.

Is there anyway of me checking, and stripping any port numbers/ipv6 detail - so I am left with JUST the IP address:

`117.89.65.117.ipv6.la` should become `117.89.65.117`
`121.58.242.206:449` should become `121.58.242.206`

This is the code I've come up with so far to check - can anyone help me adapt it to strip out the extra information above?

```
private void AddToList(String IP)
{
    Regex ipAddress = new Regex(@"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b");
    Match result = ipAddress.Match(IP);
    if (chkQuotes.Checked) IP = "\"" + IP + "\"";
    if (result.Success)
        if (cIPlist.IndexOf(IP) <= 0)
            cIPlist.Add(IP);
}
```

Comment: What does your input look like? Like `117.89.65.117.ipv6.la` or `121.58.242.206:449` as whole strings?

Comment: It seems you may use `if (chkQuotes.Checked) IP = $"\"{result.Value}\"";`. But do it after checking `if (result.Success)`.

Comment: Check https://ideone.com/gmC8uL

Comment: if you add parentesis you can acess the wanted information in group 1

Comment: @DragandDrop Why add a capturing group here? I think OP just needs to get the whole match by accessing `result.Value`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I had a group to reduce the repetition, and automatically assume I will use it to access the result.

Comment: And make the list an Hashset you wont have to check for duplicate.

Comment: Thank you both for your help.

Comment: @MarkTait Does https://ideone.com/gmC8uL work for you? Or can the input contain multiple matches?

Comment: Be careful with using `d{1,3}` for IP addresses. each IP addresses segment can't go above 255, your check is up to 999.

Comment: @wiktor-stribzew yes it does thank you - not sure why my code wasn't working, but using yours (converted to vb) is perfect - thank you! If you add as answer, I'll mark it as such.

Comment: @MarkTait [Added as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53153069/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may access the whole match value using `result.Value` instead of re-using the `IP` variable.

Also, it is a good idea to define the regex before using it inside the method to speed up things.

```
private static HashSet<string> cIPlist = new HashSet<string>();
private static readonly Regex ipAddress = new Regex(@"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b");

private void AddToList(String IP)
{
    var result = ipAddress.Match(IP);
    if (result.Success)                 # Check if there is a match
    {
        if (chkQuotes.Checked)          # If the checkbox is checked
        {
            IP = $"\"{result.Value}\""; # Add quotes around the match value
        }
        cIPlist.Add(IP);                # Add to hashset of strings
    }
}
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/cQ7riw).

Note that in case you want to restrict the regex pattern to only match IPs and not strings like `999.999.999.999`, you may use the well-known pattern from [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html):

```
new Regex(@"\b(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}\b")
```

Answer (score 1):

First we can fix the regex using https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html and reduce it a bit. With `(){3}`.

Then to eliminate duplicate you can use a `HashSet<string>` that do not allow them.

In order to add a "simple" one line linQ and for test I switch `AddToList` paramter to `params string[]`.

```
static HashSet<string> resultingList = new HashSet<string>();
static string pattern = @"(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9]";
static Regex ipRegex = new Regex(pattern);

static void AddToList(params string[] ips) =>
    resultingList.UnionWith(
        ips.Select(x => ipRegex.Match(x))
            .Where(x => x.Success)
            .Select(x => x.Value)
    );

private static void TestMethod()
{
    var inputs = new[]{
        "123.123.123.13:256",
        "123.123.123.13:256", //duplicate line
        "17.89.65.117.ipv6.la ",
        "21.58.242.206:449",
        "666.666.666.666"
    };

    AddToList(inputs);
    AddToList("127.0.0.1");
}
```